# How to compare column combinations from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables from different years, 2015 and 2016. Both tables have three columns as exampled below in table_2015:

```
customer_id || plan_type || most_recent_date

110 || monthly || 2015/10/01

111 || weekly || 2015/11/07
```

I want to see how many people had the same plan type between the years and how many people switched plan types. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What about people who are not in both tables?

Comment: I only want people who are in both tables and have either switched plan types or stayed with the same plan type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If customers are in each table only once and you only care about the overlaps, then:

```
select sum(t1.plan_type = t2.plan_type) as num_same,
       sum(t1.plan_type <> t2.plan_type) as different
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id;
```

If you actually want to compare the plan types, then use aggregation:

```
select t1.plan_type, t2.plan_type, count(*)
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
group by t1.plan_type, t2.plan_type;
```

Comment: The first part gave me the error: function sum(boolean) does not exist. But the second part was what I was looking for

Comment: @brightman1309 . . . Then you are not using MySQL (as the question is tagged).  The standard approach is `sum9(case when t1.plan_type = t2.plan_type = 1 then 1 else 0 end)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

Number with same plan type

```
select count(*) from t1 , t2
   where t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
   and t1.plan_type = t1.plan_type;
```

Number with a different plan type

```
select count(*) from t1 , t2
   where t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
   and t1.plan_type != t1.plan_type;
```

Comment: for the first query you could have `select count(*) from t1 join t2 using(customer_id,plan_type)`, and on the second you could use `join t2 on <where-clause>` but I wanted to make the differences & similarities between the two more obvious. Pretty sure the performance is unaffected, but you could try.